# how can I call /v2/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/signatures using WebRequest in c# 4.5

Tags: docusignapi

This is my code to call signatures in Docusign

An exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/7661132/users/d5751a59-f91f-412a-90bd-5314d02c9f66/signatures");

```
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-DocuSign-Authentication", _authHeader);
        //var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Empty);
        //using (var stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
        //{
        //    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        //}
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            string responseJson = sr.ReadToEnd();
            // more stuff
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using legacy authentication method. I strongly suggest you consider using our modern OAuth which is much more secure. You can read about authentication here - https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication
Secondly, I suggest you consider using our C# Client library or SDK you can find it here - https://nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/ (or the source code here - https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client) and it should help you make API calls. 
For our V2.1 API the call looks similar to what you had:

```
GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/users/{userId}/signatures
```

Assuming you had the correct accountId and userId this should work, but I'm not sure your authentication headers are correct.